# Rails models choices field

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to Rails. In Django there is a choices option for model fields like this:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    FRESHMAN = 'FR'
    SOPHOMORE = 'SO'
    JUNIOR = 'JR'
    SENIOR = 'SR'
    GRADUATE = 'GR'
    YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES = [
        (FRESHMAN, 'Freshman'),
        (SOPHOMORE, 'Sophomore'),
        (JUNIOR, 'Junior'),
        (SENIOR, 'Senior'),
        (GRADUATE, 'Graduate'),
    ]
    year_in_school = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        choices=YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES,
        default=FRESHMAN,
    )
```

What is the way to achieve the same thing in rails? In my case I would like to have an `activity` field which can have values `to-read, reading, read, not-finished, reading_again`. Thanks in advance

Comment: I think this is what you want https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.4.4/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello in rails you can add validation to your model like that :

```
class Student < ApplicationRecord
  validates :activity, inclusion: { in: ["to-read", "reading", "read", "not-finished", "reading_again"],
    message: "%{value} is not a valid activity" }
end
```

choices must be put in your form view like that :

```
<%= form_with model: @student, class: "" do |f| %>
  <%= select_tag(:activity,
    options_for_select(["to-read", "reading", "read", "not-finished", "reading_again"], @student.activity) %>
  <%= f.submit "Create" %>
<% end %>
```

And in your db schema you should have :

```
create_table "students", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "activity"
  t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
end
```

Don't forget : if your db schema is not right you have to do a migration and not directly edit your `schema.rb` : https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html

Hope this answer to your question

Best, Théo